# Why does the CheckBox Html Helper render a hidden input field?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I often use the built in CheckBox HtmlHelper as it allows me to easily specify the checked state of the element like this

```
@Html.CheckBox("Test",Model.IsChecked);
```

vs creating it on the view like so

```
@if(Model.IsChecked)
{
  <input id="test" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
}
else
{
  <input id="test" type="checkbox"  />
}
```

However when inspecting the html generated by the helper i can see it renders this html.

```
<input id="Test" name="Test" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Test" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

I can't work out why there is a hidden field input as well, what is it used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form data submitted by the browser does not include keys and values for unchecked checkboxes. Without the hidden field, there is no way for the server-side code to determine if the checkbox is present in the form and is unchecked or if it does not exist on the client at all.

`Html.CheckBox` creates hidden field with the same name as the name of the `input` with `type="checkbox"`, therefore the submitted value is `"true,false"` for checked checkbox, and `"false"` for unchecked checkbox.